# Best way to fix type conversion warnings in c++

Tags: c++, windows, types, warnings

So, I've never been sure what to do when I get warnings like these, so I wanted other professional programmer's advice.  When I get a warning (not an error) of the sort

> warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'ULONG', possible loss
>   of data

(omitted other contextual code)

```
wchar_t pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = L"user";
wchar_t pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1] = L"password";

// ..

COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;

// ...

memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
authIdent.PasswordLength = wcslen(pszPwd);
authIdent.UserLength = wcslen(pszName);
```

The issue clearly is that wcslen() returns a size_t and authIdent.PasswordLength is a ULONG.  What would be the best way to take care of warnings like these?  Is there a winapi function they expect me to use instead of wcslen()?

Edit:  Thanks for all the great responses everyone!

Comment: Change the variable types to `size_t`?

Comment: Does `static_cast<ULONG>(wcslen())` take care of it?

Comment: @NathanOliver doing that would require me to edit a WinAPI structure/class.  Pretty sure that would be the worst thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural type for a string lenght is `size_t`. In practice the size of a string will fit in a `ULONG` as well as in a `size_t`. Nevertheless such an assignment is definitely worth a warning. Imagine this stupid error:

```
ULONG x = 0;
authIdent.PasswordLength = x - 1;
```

It is easy to claim that such error never happens, but it is just as easy to prevent such error by providing a less error prone interface (that also prevents that ugly `memset` to appear in user code):

```
struct my_COAUTHIDENTITY {
    private:
        COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;
    public: 
        my_COAUTHIDENTITY() {
            memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        }
        void setPasswd(wstring passwd) {
            ...
            authIdent.PasswordLength = static_cast<ULONG>(passwd.size());
        }
 };
```

Comment: How often should I be creating wrapper structures/classes like this?  Should I do it any time I have to use "uglier" code?

Comment: @SaniT404 that completely depends on your style and how much you want to invest. However, only the fact that it requires me to call `memset` would be always reason enough for me to hide it because when I write code I dont want to write code in terms of accessing bits of memory but in terms of what the code really is about (ie higher level abstractions)

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Each compiler warning needs dealing with on a case by case basis.

You're getting this warning on your platform since `ULONG` is a 32 bit unsigned, and `std::size_t` is a 64 bit unsigned.

But given that (1) it's unlikely that your string will be longer than a `ULONG`, and (2) that a conversion between two unsigned types is *always* well-defined, I'd do the pragmatic thing and use a `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<ULONG>(wcslen(pszPwd))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you can reasonably trust that the length will fit in a ULONG you can safely use:

```
static_cast<ULONG>(wcslen(pszPwd))
```

Otherwise you can:

- check for the value before casting
- or use a template to do it automatically: 
  [https://stackoverflow.com /questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts](https://stackoverflow.com%20/questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts)

Comment: your link is broken :/

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to provide a `safe_numeric_cast` function which performs unchecked `static_cast`'s in a non-debug build while checking narrowing conversions in a debug build.

e.g.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>
//#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>  // enable if you have boost 1.65+
#include <iostream>

extern void foo(std::size_t);

struct conversion_failure
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        #ifdef NDEBUG
        // welcome to undefined behaviour - or we could log, throw, etc.
        #else
            std::cerr << "conversion out of bounds" << std::endl;
//            std::cerr << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
            std::exit(100);
        #endif
    }
};

template<class From, class To, class Enable = void>
struct safe_cast;

template<class Both> struct safe_cast<Both, Both>
{
    Both operator()(Both in) const {
        return in;
    }
};

template<
    class Big, 
    class Small
> 
struct safe_cast<Big, Small, std::enable_if_t<(std::numeric_limits<Big>::digits > std::numeric_limits<Small>::digits)>>
{
    Small operator()(Big from) const {
    using to_limits = std::numeric_limits<Small>;
    assert(from >= Big(to_limits::min()) && from <= Big(to_limits::max()) );
    return Small(from);
    }
};

template<
    class Small, 
    class Big
> 
struct safe_cast<Small, Big, std::enable_if_t<(std::numeric_limits<Big>::digits > std::numeric_limits<Small>::digits)>>
{
    Big operator()(Small from) const {
        return from;
    }
};


template
<
    class To, 
    class From
>
auto safe_numeric_cast(From&& from)
-> decltype(auto)
{
    auto conv = safe_cast<From, To>();
    return conv(from);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    auto y = safe_numeric_cast<long long>(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    auto z = safe_numeric_cast<int>(y);
    std::cout << z << std::endl;

    // should abort on debug build, UB on release
    auto zz = safe_numeric_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max());
    std::cout << zz << std::endl;
}
```